# Null pointer in ElasticsearchException.getIndex

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to query an index, I have checked the index name . the same piece of code excutes perfectly on one machine while on the other it gives me this exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.getIndex(ElasticsearchException.java:1083) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar!/:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.toString(ElasticsearchException.java:696) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar!/:6.4.3]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.springframework.core.NestedExceptionUtils.buildMessage(NestedExceptionUtils.java:52) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException.getMessage(NestedServletException.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:238) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

Now I have checked the following

- The elastic index in same on both the machine.
- I can fire the same query on both machines and they work perfectly on 
  both.
- The elastic version on the machine on which this doesn't work is 6.5.1 
  and on the machine on which it works is 6.2.4

If the index didn't exist then there is a different exception that we get, I am not able to understand the reason behind this exception.

Edit 1 : here is the query I am using

```
  "from": 0,
  "size": 6,
  "timeout": "1000ms",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "searchName": {
              "query": "new delh",
              "operator": "OR",
              "analyzer": "standard",
              "fuzziness": "1",
              "prefix_length": 8,
              "max_expansions": 200,
              "minimum_should_match": "100%",
              "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
              "lenient": false,
              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "isSearchEnabled": {
              "value": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "searchName": {
              "query": "new delh",
              "operator": "OR",
              "analyzer": "standard",
              "fuzziness": "2",
              "prefix_length": 1,
              "max_expansions": 200,
              "minimum_should_match": "100%",
              "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
              "lenient": false,
              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "entityDisplayOrder": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "propertyCount": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Update your question with the query that you are using.

Comment: the query should not make any difference as it works fine on both the machines, but still i have added it for your reference @leandrojmp